# Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

does anybody know why my update is not working if I try to set two of the columns at the same time?

```
  UPDATE mytable
    SET [Customer] = RIGHT([Customer], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Customer])) -1) ,
        [Segment] = RIGHT([Segment], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Segment])) -1)
    WHERE CHARINDEX('#', [Customer]) > 0 OR
              CHARINDEX('#', [Segment]) > 0
```

If I run the query with updating just one column, then it works as it is expected to work. If I run with both, I get the following err:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function. The statement has been terminated.
```

I know that this can happen when CHARINDEX returns 0 but I am trying to control that with the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.  If you really want to control it, replace it with an `AND`:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET [Customer] = RIGHT([Customer], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Customer])) -1) ,
        [Segment] = RIGHT([Segment], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Segment])) -1)
    WHERE CHARINDEX('#', [Customer]) > 0 AND
          CHARINDEX('#', [Segment]) > 0
```

Alternatively:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET [Customer] = (CASE WHEN Customer LIKE '%#%'
                           THEN RIGHT([Customer], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Customer])) -1)
                           ELSE Customer
                      END)
        [Segment] = (CASE WHEN Segment LIKE '%#%'
                          THEN RIGHT([Segment], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Segment])) -1)
                          ELSE Segment
                     END)
    WHERE Customer LIKE '%#%' OR Segment LIKE '%#%';
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,

I am sorry that I did not mention it, but I tried that with same result .. Then the query runs but it always affects 0 rows.. but I know that it should affect all the rows becaus when I run it individually, it affects all of them

Comment: Ok, I believe it was a case of empty data now.. I did not notice that there is not some data imported to the table yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error message is a negative value being passed to the `RIGHT` function. From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177532.aspx):

> **integer_expression**
>   Is a positive integer that specifies how many characters of character_expression will be returned. If integer_expression is negative, an error is returned.

Your `WHERE` condition contains an `OR`, which will allow rows without a "#" to be included where the "other" column does contain one.

Try amending your `OR` to an `AND`:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET [Customer] = RIGHT([Customer], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Customer])) -1) ,
        [Segment] = RIGHT([Segment], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Segment])) -1)
    WHERE CHARINDEX('#', [Customer]) > 0 AND
              CHARINDEX('#', [Segment]) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update both and **sometimes** one or the other will have the "#" then you can use:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
    Customer = CASE
                   WHEN CHARINDEX('#', Customer) > 0 THEN RIGHT(Customer, CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(Customer)) -1)
                   ELSE Customer
               END,
    Segment = CASE
                   WHEN CHARINDEX('#', Segment) > 0 THEN RIGHT(Segment, CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(Segment)) -1)
                   ELSE Segment
               END
WHERE
    CHARINDEX('#', Customer) > 0 OR
    CHARINDEX('#', Segment) > 0
```

Of course, alternatively you could break it down into two `UPDATE` statements, but I think that this one will run faster since it will only have to make one pass through the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
    UPDATE mytable SET 
    [Customer] = Case When CHARINDEX('#', [Customer]) > 0 Then RIGHT([Customer], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Customer])) -1) Else [Customer] End ,
    [Segment] = Case When CHARINDEX('#', [Segment]) > 0 Then RIGHT([Segment], CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE([Segment])) -1) Else [Segment] End
    WHERE
    CHARINDEX('#', [Customer]) > 0 OR
    CHARINDEX('#', [Segment]) > 0
```

Comment: Maybe this is actually the best solution. Thank you!